# Erroneous Results calculating the gradient of an image with ITK

Tags: c++, gradient, vtk, itk

In the header file, I declare all of this types, The “Gradient ImageFilter” is for calculate the gradient of a 2D image, and the “VectorIndexSelectionCastImageFilter” is for selecting the ’x’ and ‘y’ component of the gradient calculating, due to the fact that the result of computing th gradient is a vector image.

```
typedef double      operatorValueType;
typedef double      outputValueType;
typedef double      InputPixelType;
typedef  itk::Image<InputPixelType, 2> InputImageType;
typedef  itk::GradientImageFilter< InputImageType, operatorValueType, outputValueType>     GradientFilterType;
//for extracting a scalar from the vector image
typedef double       OutputPixelTypeImage;
typedef double       ComponentType;
typedef  itk::CovariantVector<ComponentType,2> OutputPixelType;
typedef  itk::Image <OutputPixelType, 2> OutputImageType;
typedef  itk::VectorIndexSelectionCastImageFilter<OutputImageType,InputImageType> SelectionFilterType; // < intputType , outputType>
```

After the declarations, the main part of interest of the code is below:

```
GradientFilterType::Pointer gradientFilter = GradientFilterType::New();
gradientFilter->SetInput(T_g->GetOutput());  // From T_g (is a reader) comes the image
gradientFilter->Update();

SelectionFilterType::Pointer componentExtractor_x = SelectionFilterType::New();
SelectionFilterType::Pointer componentExtractor_y = SelectionFilterType::New();

componentExtractor_x->SetIndex(0);// x component of the gradient
componentExtractor_y->SetIndex(1);// y component of the gradient

componentExtractor_x->SetInput(gradientFilter->GetOutput());
componentExtractor_y->SetInput(gradientFilter->GetOutput());

componentExtractor_x->Update();
componentExtractor_y->Update();
```

It seems that everything works fine, but the problem is that when I read the image and I compare it with the calculation of the gradient in Matlab (which I assume to be correct) the results are completely different…Anyone has used before the “VectorIndexSelectionCastImageFilter” and see something strange? Or in the process of calculating the gradient?

Thanks so much!

Antonio

Answer (score 2):

ITK should respect voxel spacing in the computations.  Do you images have isotropic unit spacing?

This could account for the differences with matlab.

Comment: Yes, you are right, the solution was to add the following line: gradientFilter->SetUseImageSpacingOff(); // for derivation in isotropic pixel space

Answer (score 1):

The problem was in the spacing of the image, just by adding this line:

```
gradientFilter->SetUseImageSpacingOff(); // for derivation in isotropic pixel space
```

the problem was solved, and the derivation was done in an isotropic space

Comment: NOTE:  This is why using matlab for real world medical imaging can be very dangerous.  Most image captures are an-isostropic for practical reasons.  Compute in voxel space can produce subtle differences that can affect interpretation and ultimately patient safety.